# max() issue in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, max

I'm using Oracle SQL and i need some help with max() function.

I have the following table:

```
ID  | Type | Price | Quantity
 1  |  A   |  10   |    2
 2  |  B   |  5    |    5
 3  |  C   |  10   |    3
 4  |  A   |  8    |    7
 5  |  A   |  6    |    9
 6  |  A   |  7    |    5
 7  |  B   |  15   |    3
 8  |  A   |  20   |    4
 9  |  A   |  3    |    7
 10 |  B   |  11   |    8
```

I need to aggregate the table by Type column. For each group of Type (A, B, C), i need to select the price and the quantity of max(id).

I this case:

```
 ID  | Type | Price | Quantity
  9  |  A   |  3    |    7
  10 |  B   |  11   |    8
  3  |  C   |  10   |    3
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` won't help you with this. You can use the `row_number` partitioning function.

```
select id, type, price, quantity
from
(
select yourtable.*,
    row_number() over (partition by type order by id desc) rn
from yourtable
) v
where rn = 1
```

Comment: The subquery has a problem: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @Omri: you need to "qualify" the `*` in Oracle: `select yourtable.*, row_number() ...`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Select t.* From 
(Select Max(ID) As ID From Table
 Group By Type) tmp
Join Table t On t.ID = tmp.ID
```